# Angular map file not found

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, dictionary, http-status-code-404

I've just downloaded a fresh copy of angular.min.js, and I'm getting a 404 on angular.min.js.map, which I'm not including in my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in Chrome:

```
GET http://angular.dev/js/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the angular.min.js file in a text editor. There will be a comment at the end like this:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=angular.min.js.map
```

Delete that and the error will disappear.

A map file facilitates regenerating the minified version of a script based on changes to a non-minified version. Since you won't be making changes to angular.js, you don't need the map.

Comment: Thanks. Also found this intro to source maps some may find useful: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere source map files basically turn minified code into its un-minified version for debugging purpose.

> You can get rid of this error {angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)}
>   message by following anyone below :-

**First way**

1.You just have to find the same .map file for angular.min.js which you have included.

> (eg. For angularJs minified version 1.5.6 .map files can be downloaded from [Here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/) )

Just copy-paste them to the same directory where you have uploaded your minified js files and it'll stop complaining.

The reason they get fetched is the below line which you can find when you open the angular.min.js file.

```
//# sourceMappingURL=angular.min.js.map
```

which can be found at the end of the angular.min.js file.

**Second way**

2. If you don't want to add the .map files to your project.
   You can remove above line and it'll stop fetch attempt, but if you plan on debugging it's always good to keep the source maps linked.