# Display list of JSON element in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and Javascript. I am trying to print the JSON object in tree structure. For this i have picked some piece of code from JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

The code is working fine at JSFiddle even with the my JSON. But when i am trying to run in my system, It is displaying  [[object HTMLUListElement]] .

below is js.js -

```
  myApp.controller('viewController', ["$scope", "$http", "$stateParams", function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

  var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "/DDOEnvDashboard/getDetails/getEnvironmentDetails/?_envName=" + $stateParams.envId,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'dataType': 'json'
            }
        };

       $http(req).
            success(function(data, status, headers){

                $scope.roleList = [{"data": "dev",
                        "incrementalPath": "dev",
                        "children": [{"data": "SERVER2",
                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2",
                                "children": [{"data": "CLUSTER2",
                                        "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER2",
                                        "children": [{"data": "APPLICATION1",
                                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER2|APPLICATION1",
                                                "children": []
                                            }]
                                    },
                                    {"data": "CLUSTER1",
                                    "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER1",
                                    "children": [{"data": "APPLICATION2",
                                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER1|APPLICATION2",
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION1",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER1|APPLICATION1",
                                            "children": []
                                            }]
                                    },
                                    {"data": "CLUSTER3",
                                    "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER3",
                                    "children": [{"data": "APPLICATION3",
                                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER3|APPLICATION3",
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION2",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER3|APPLICATION2",
                                            "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION1",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER2|CLUSTER3|APPLICATION1",
                                            "children": []
                                            }]
                                    }]
                            },
                            {"data": "SERVER1",
                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1",
                            "children": [{"data": "CLUSTER1",
                                    "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER1",
                                    "children": [{"data": "APPLICATION2",
                                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER1|APPLICATION2",
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION1",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER1|APPLICATION1",
                                            "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION3",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER1|APPLICATION3",
                                            "children": []
                                            }]
                                    },
                                    {"data": "CLUSTER2",
                                    "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER2",
                                    "children": [{"data": "APPLICATION2",
                                                "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER2|APPLICATION2",
                                                "children": []
                                            },
                                            {"data": "APPLICATION1",
                                            "incrementalPath": "dev|SERVER1|CLUSTER2|APPLICATION1",
                                            "children": []
                                            }]
                                    }]
                            }]
                    }];
            }).
            error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('There is some internal error. Please try again later.');
            });}]);
```

angular.treeview.js file is below :

```
(function(f) {
f.module("angularTreeview", []).directive("treeModel", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(a, g, viewparams) {

            var treemodel=viewparams.treeModel,
                nodelabel=viewparams.nodeLabel||"label",
                nodechildren=viewparams.nodeChildren||"children",
                divhtml='<ul><li data-ng-repeat="node in '+treemodel+'"><i class="collapsed" data-ng-show="node.'+nodechildren+'.length && node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node, $event)"></i><i class="expanded" data-ng-show="node.'+nodechildren+'.length && !node.collapsed" data-ng-click="selectNodeHead(node, $event)"></i><i class="normal" data-ng-hide="node.'+nodechildren+'.length"></i> <span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="selectNodeLabel(node, $event)">{{node.'+nodelabel+'}}</span><div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-model="node.'+nodechildren+'" data-node-id='+(viewparams.nodeId||"id")+" data-node-label="+nodelabel+" data-node-children="+nodechildren+"></div></li></ul>";


            treemodel && treemodel.length && (viewparams.angularTreeview?(
                    a.$watch(treemodel,function(m,b){g.empty().html($compile(divhtml)(a))}, !1),
                        a.selectNodeHead=a.selectNodeHead||function(a,b){
                            b.stopPropagation&&b.stopPropagation();
                            b.preventDefault&&b.preventDefault();
                            b.cancelBubble=!0;
                            b.returnValue=!1;
                            a.collapsed=!a.collapsed
                        }, 
                        a.selectNodeLabel=a.selectNodeLabel||function(viewparams,b){
                            b.stopPropagation&&b.stopPropagation(); 
                            b.preventDefault&&b.preventDefault(); 
                            b.cancelBubble=!0; 
                            b.returnValue=!1; 
                            a.currentNode&&a.currentNode.selected&&(
                                    a.currentNode.selected=void 0
                                );
                                viewparams.selected="selected";
                                a.currentNode=viewparams
                        }):g.html($compile(divhtml)(a)))

        }
    }
})})(angular);
```

html page is :

`

```
<div ng-app="myApp"><div ng-controller="viewController">

<div style="margin:10px 0 30px 0; padding:10px; background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:5px; font:12px Tahoma;"><span><b>Selected Node</b> : {currentNode.data}}</span></div>
<div
  data-angular-treeview="true"
  data-tree-model="roleList"
  data-node-id="incrementalPath"
  data-node-label="data"
  data-node-children="children" >
</div>

</div>
</div>`
```

I have linked both JS scripts in index html files. How can i display data as tree structure ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is displaying  `[[object HTMLUListElement]]` in the output, the script is working fine. You need to include `jquery.min.js` to show tree view. Include JQuery library in your **HTML** page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also the line for initializing the module is missing from your `js.js` file.

```
//angular module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview']);
```

**Edit:** In `.success` function, add following line line:

```
$scope.roleList = $scope.roleList;
```

Comment: Thanks @Suyog for response. It was already initialized, i forgot to add the line here. Also i have added the dependency as mentioned. But still it is not working.

Comment: have you checked console for any possible errors? Because I have integrated the Fiddle code on my localhost and it is working exactly similar to fiddle output.

Comment: as before adding `jquery.min.js` I was also getting the output as `[[object HTMLUListElement]]`.

Comment: Yes, no error is displayed there except http://localhost:8080/DDOEnvDashboard/scripts/angular.min.js.map not found. But i think this is not effecting the output as i have already added angular.min.js.

Comment: I think you will also have to remove this error. Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860416/angular-map-file-not-found  ,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425841/angular-min-js-map-not-found-what-is-it-exactly

Comment: I removed the source file mapping from angular.min.js . but still it is not displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks Suyog, It has resolved now.Actually i was adding more than one javascript files (js.js and jquery.min.js). After changing the order it is working fine.

Comment: Good luck.. Happy coding!